How cloud i convert the region that i use yolov5 detected in depth map to point cloud and calculate some distance in the item
enter image description here
as i said above, after using yolo to detect some locations, I just want to convert these regions into cloudpoints,and using formula to calculate distance, what the first step I outght to do? the only thing i did before is just converting the whole img into cloudpoints
